# Get objects from collection A where the ID of A exists in a collection of B objects

Tags: c#, linq

i have a collection A of person objects, and the person has a property called 'ID'.
I also have a collection B of personcountry objects, and the personcountry object has a property personId.

Now i want to select all persons in collection A, for which there is a object in collection B with its personId.

So with this data

```
person (collection A List[Person]) 
person id  name
    1      John
    2      John
    3      John2
    4      Pete
    5      Bill
    6      Samantha
```

and this collection B (List[Country])

```
country id  personid
1             1
1             3
2             5
```

i want the person records with id 1,3 and 5 from collection A.

I did manage to do it with 2 collections of ints witht the intersect method, but i'm stuck when using the two object collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var q = Persons.Where(p => Countries.Any(c => p.Id== c.PersonId))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a join

```
var query = (from p in persons
            join pc in personcountry on p.Id equals pc.PersonId
            select p).AsEnumerable();
```